# windows service exception in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I will be tested the application as windows application then it will be stored the datetime in MySQL data base.When I will be start this application using windows service it will be thrown this exception.

```
error [HY000][MySQL][ODBC 3.51 Driver] [MySqlid -6.0.11-alpha-community]incorrect datetime value " 5/6/2011 9:00:00 AM" for column column-name at row1
```

Windows application take the system format & my system format is yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss
in windows service which format is used.

```
query18 += "select '" + obj8 + "' as DTvalue ,'" + date8 + "' as DTdatelogged1 ,'" + OpcGroup.QualityToString(e8.sts[counter8].Quality) + "' as DTquality ,'" + DateTime.FromFileTime(e8.sts[counter8].TimeStamp) + "' as DTtimestamp ,'" + e8.sts[counter8].HandleClient + "' as DTparamID Union " + Environment.NewLine;

UpdateQuery = Update parameter t Left join + Environment.NewLine;
                    UpdateQuery8 +=  (  + query18 +  ) Temp on" + Environment.NewLine;
                    UpdateQuery8 += t.itemID=Temp.DTparamID+ Environment.NewLine;
                    UpdateQuery8 += set paramvalue=DTvalue, date_logged1=DTdatelogged1,Quality=                         DTquality,date_logged=DTtimestamp   + Environment.NewLine;
                    UpdateQuery8 += where t.groupID=9 and t.itemID=Temp.DTparamID;
```

my query likethis timestamp value is 129500892576718750 it will be convert DateTime.FromFileTime() function converted value like '2011-05-17 12:30:57' in windows application it will be write into mysql database 
but in windows service converted value like 2011/05/17 12:30:57 PM it will be not accepted by the MYSQL database same thing i will be used in the windows service

now

```
UpdateQuery8 = "Update parameter " + Environment.NewLine;
                        UpdateQuery8 += "set paramvalue=@paramvalue,date_logged1=@date_logged1,Quality=@Quality,date_logged=@date_logged" + Environment.NewLine;
UpdateQuery8 += "where groupID=9 and itemID=@itemID";
                        cmd8 = new OdbcCommand(UpdateQuery8, con136);
  cmd8.Parameters.Add("@paramvalue",  obj8.ToString());
  cmd8.Parameters.Add("@date_logged1", date8);
 cmd8.Parameters.Add("@Quality", OpcGroup.QualityToString(e8.sts[counter8].Quality));
  cmd8.Parameters.Add("@date_logged", dt);
  cmd8.Parameters.Add("@itemID",e8.sts[counter8].HandleClient);
  cmd8.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

it will be execute but there no updation in database

Please help me in this regard.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Always use [parametrized queries](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html) to pass data to the DB driver. Then it is up to the driver to format your dates correctly, and you avoid being susceptible to [SQL-Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Answer (score 0):

Create a datetime and format it the way YOU want. Not the system defaults, not the casual user defaults, the one you want.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
String str = dt.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```

This should lead to "20110517" if i'm not mistaking.

Bonus points are given if you use one of the better answers setting the code locale to the one used by the mysql server. But the one above should give you a way that works.